# Postfix with Amavis returns "name=localhost type=A: Host not found" in mail.log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, amavis

Full error:

```
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/pickup[5589]: 39332276875: uid=0 from=<fredflinstone>
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/cleanup[5605]: 39332276875: message-id=<20161223194431.39332276875@example.com>
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/qmgr[5590]: 39332276875: from=<fredflinstone@example.com>, size=300, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/smtp[5607]: 39332276875: to=<FredGSanford@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=localhost type=A: Host not found)
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/cleanup[5605]: 453F3276876: message-id=<20161223194431.453F3276876@example.com>
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/bounce[5608]: 39332276875: sender non-delivery notification: 453F3276876
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/qmgr[5590]: 453F3276876: from=<>, size=2273, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/qmgr[5590]: 39332276875: removed
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/local[5609]: 453F3276876: to=<FredGSanford@example.com>, orig_to=<fredflinstone@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Dec 23 19:44:31 example.com postfix/qmgr[5590]: 453F3276876: removed
```

Localhost is in /etc/hosts. Can ping it. Could it be nsswitch.conf, or host.conf? Mail delivers fine when I disable amavis from postfix. Here is my postfix configuration:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[localhost]:10024
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = , check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
hosts:          files resolv [!UNAVAIL=return] mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

/etc/host.conf

```
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.7.4  localhost example.com localhost.example.com
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

/etc/postfix/master.conf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

policy-spf unix    -       n       n       -       0     spawn
      user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf

smtp-amavis unix    -       -       -       -       2     smtp
     -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
     -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
     -o smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer=no

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n    -       -       -       -     smtpd
     -o content_filter=
     -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
     -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
     -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
     -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
     -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
     -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
     -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
     -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
     -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
     -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
     -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
     -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
     -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
     -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
     -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
     -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
     -o smtpd_milters=
     -o local_recipient_maps=
     -o relay_recipient_maps=
```

NOTE Content filter. If I comment that out, mail delivers just fine. So the problem is with amavis? New installation on new server. Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: That's really, um, odd. What's in your `/etc/hosts`, your `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: When I installed the system, I disabled systemd-resolved and removed resolv from /etc/nsswitch.conf. I realized that was not a good idea and re-enabled the service and added resolv back to nsswitch.conf. However, that may have broke amavis. I copied these files into postfix, they all match. No errors or warnings when starting postfix except for symbolics.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in `/etc/hosts`.

You've defined `10.0.7.4  localhost`, which is a great way to break localhost. This should not be present and should be removed immediately.

Comment: Updated hosts and copied it to /var/spool/postfix/etc. Restarted. Still broken. Dec 24 17:29:44 example postfix/smtp[38093]: 713E0276A7D: to=<gilligan@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.08, delays=0.03/0.04/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain n
ame not found. Name service error for name=localhost type=A: Host not found)

Comment: fix was to change [localhost] to [127.0.0.1] in main.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the amavisd content filter line in main.cf from localhost to 127.0.0.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: Sounds more like that would hide the symptom rather than fix the problem.